# Generating a range of values in Pig without a file

Tags: apache-pig

I'm trying to generate reports based on time ranges and I'd like to be able to segment things into different slices.

For example, I have some data that I'd like to group into overlapping ranges (a 24 hour window that I'd like to slide by hour increments over a period of 7 days).

I don't see any way to do this without generating the time ranges externally into a file that gets read by pig.

Answer (score 0):

The answers you get for this are very dependent on how you need the dates formatted for the `JOIN`.  I answered a similarish question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18004054/pig-0-11-1-count-groups-in-a-time-range/18005304#18005304), and we can use the same principle from it here (expanding out the date range).  Also, I'm pretty sure you can get away with just having a blank file as the second input.  You will need to have at least something to do a `FOREACH` on, and the UDF can do all of the work.

I'll provide some example code (if needed) once I know how the dates need to be formatted.